# Make object file for each source file and merge them as binary

Tags: makefile, solaris

This is the first time I write a Makefile. I tried the following Makefile to create object file for each source file in src folder, merge them and create the binary file out.exe in the bin folder.

```
SRC=src
INC=inc
OBJ=obj
BIN=bin

CC=/usr/sfw/bin/gcc
FLAGS=-g -m64 -Wall

ALL_INC=-I$(INC)

CC_LIBS=-lsocket -lnsl -lpthread -lm -lstdc++ -lclntsh

$(BIN)/out.exe : $(OBJ)/%.o
   $(CC) $(ALL_INC) $(FLAGS) -o out.exe

$(OBJ)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.cpp $(INC)/%.h
   $(CC) $(ALL_INC) $(FLAGS) -c $<

clean:
   rm -f obj/*.o bin/ussd
```

On invoking make I am getting the following error.

```
make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `obj/%.o'
```

Below I have given the list of make tools available in my system and their version

```
/bin - dmake - Sun Distributed Make 7.7
/usr/bin - dmake - Sun Distributed Make 7.7
/usr/ccs/bin - make - Unknow version
/usr/sfw/bin - gmake - GNU Make 3.80
/usr/xpg4/bin - Unknow version
/usr/local/bin - make - GNU Make version 3.79.1
```

Comment: Are you using GNU make?  Or some kind of Solaris make?  Because that error is not a message any version of GNU make will print.  Pattern rules are not specified by the POSIX standard for make and so different versions implement them differently (or don't implement them at all): you should specify which make implementation you're using.

Comment: how to find the make implementation details

Comment: Use `man make` to see the man page and see which options are available for showing those details, or run `make -v`, `make --version`, `make -version`, `make -h`, or `make --help`, one or more of which will likely give you that information.

Comment: I am in Solaris environment. Non of the commands you have given show the version. With man command I found this SunOS 5.10

Comment: If none of those work then you're definitely not using GNU make.

Comment: check the versions I have updated in question

Comment: It's nice you have all those options.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I am using this /usr/ccs/bin - make - Unknow version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
$(BIN)/out.exe : $(OBJ)/%.o
   $(CC) $(ALL_INC) $(FLAGS) -o out.exe
```

$(BIN)/out.exe must know all files it depends on

Add this:

```
SRCS=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp) // List all source files
OBJS=$(SRCS:$(SRC)/%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o) // List all object files (one for each source file)
```

Then change the out.exe rule:

```
$(BIN)/out.exe : $(OBJS)
```

Comment: runs without error but not creating any object or binary file

Comment: You have to keep the recipe part of the rule.  Carl's example just showed you how to change the prerequisite list.  All the rest should be the same.

Comment: Note that $(wildcard ...) requires use of GNU make (aka `gmake`), and won't work with the Solaris make or dmake programs.